# C Input only decimals

Tags: c, string, input, numerics

I'm trying to restrict the input to only numerics in a simple C application however I get a warning. I suspect it's to do with the following segment. Is version one the proper way of doing things? Thanks.

```
    for(i=0;i< strlen(string); i++)
{
    if( string[i]<"0" || string[i]>"9")
        valid= FALSE;
}
```

OR

```
    for(i=0;i< strlen(string); i++)
{
    if( string[i]<'0' || string[i]>'9')
        valid= FALSE;
}
```

rest of my code is

```
    void main()

{
    char number[4];
    printf("Please enter a decimal number: ");
    gets(number);   
    if (numeric(number))
        printf("'%s' is a valid number\n", number);
    else
        printf("'%s' is an invalid number\n", number);
}
```

To clarify I have to do the check in the fashion given according to the exercise I'm doing. Thanks.

Comment: The second one is (more) right.

Comment: So... you _don't_ want to check for a decimal point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version one is entirely wrong. It does pointer comparisons, because string literals decay to pointers and characters are promoted to `int`.

Version two is close, though you should really use `isdigit` from `<ctype.h>`.

Btw., are you aware that `i < strlen(string)` in a loop termination condition turns linear-time algorithms into quadratic-time ones?

Comment: Thanks the exercise I was given we have to use this approach. But I can't seem to locate my error

Comment: @MarioPen: well, does using the second option (or `isdigit`) solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `if (scanf ("%d", &n)==1)` or  call `strtol` ?

Comment: `strtol` would work, but `sscanf` wouldn't be equivalent. For example, his code says `1a` is invalid, but `sscanf` would still convert the 1 to a number, so it would return 1.

Comment: I wrote `scanf` on purpose, assuming he is reading from `stdin`